# How can I send an array from Controller to JavaScript in Laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel

There is data that needs to be sent to View from Controller. From what I've read, this is the way to do it,  but the alert doesn't show anything in the page. 
Here's the method I use in Controller:

```
public function provider() {
    $sites = array(
    0 => "Mon", 
    1 => "Tue", 
    2 => "Wed", 
    3 => "Thu",
    4 => "Fri", 
    5 => "Sat",
    6 => "Sun",);
    return ($sites);
}
```

And here is the javascript piece I use in View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function provider() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/resultsprovirder',
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                alert(data);
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function() {
                alert(data);
                alert("error");
            }
        });
     };
</script>
```

Also, is there a more secure way than AJAX?

Comment: If you are sending data from your backend to your frontend, why do it in a `POST` call instead than a `GET` call?

Comment: 1. Do a `GET` not `POST`. 2. your success data is wrong. It needs to be `success: function(data)` 3.Your PHP Array function should be converted to JSON so javascript can read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first your code structure if wrong .lets try a simple example.

#### Example

In MVC frameworks like laravel you should define your routes :

#### yourproject/app/HTTP/routes.php

`Route::get('/',PageController@home);`

Now lets build our Controller: In your teminal (cmd in windows):
`php artisan make:controller PageController`

And your controller file ( **yourproject/app/http/controllers/PageController.php** ) in your class :

```
public function home()
    {
        $sites = array(
            0 => "Mon",
            1 => "Tue",
            2 => "Wed",
            3 => "Thu",
            4 => "Fri",
            5 => "Sat",
            6 => "Sun",);
        return view('home',['Sites' => $sites] );// This Line says that your home view is in yourproject/resources/views/home.blade.php and pass $Sites to that file
    }
```

Finally.in **yourproject/resources/views/home.blade.php** :

```
<script>
    var sites= @json($Sites);//@json is Blade shortcode for json_encode
</script>
```

Now you can use your **sites** var in your page js!
Ajax used when you want exchange datas between server and client without refreshing all of the page and not for sending data from controller in first of load ! and in parentheses : if you want use ajax in laravel you should set AjaxSetup for avoiding CSRF attacks.before your ajax request :

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
                  headers: {
                      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                  }
```

This is The most secure way to send var to your views . Hope this help you,
Best Regard,Mohammad

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

**In your controller**

```
public function provider() 
{

  $sites = [
    0 => "Mon", 
    1 => "Tue", 
    2 => "Wed", 
    3 => "Thu",
    4 => "Fri", 
    5 => "Sat",
    6 => "Sun"
  ];

  $response = [
     'msg' => 'Success',
     'status' => 1,
     'data' => $sites
  ];

  return response()->json($response);
```

}

**In your view file**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        getdata();
    });

    function getdata(){
       var ajx = new XMLHttpRequest();
       ajx.onreadystatechange = function(){
           if(ajx.readyState == 4 && ajx.status == 200){
               var demo = JSON.parse(ajx.responseText);
               console.log(demo.data);
           }
       }

       ajx.open("GET",'/resultsprovirder',true);
       ajx.send();
    }
</script>
```

You will get your data in demo.data or check your console.